# If $X^T$ is full rank, then $X^TX$ is positive definite?

Tags: positive-definite

I read that If $X^T$ is full **column** rank ($X$ is not necessarily square), then $X^TX$ is positive definite, and I'm trying to see why this is the case.

I know that if $X^T$ is full **column** rank, then $A=X^TX$ is also full rank. We also know that $A$ has only positive entries, and that $A$ is symmetric. But knowing this doesn't seem to guarantee positive definiteness.

What is an intuitive way to arrive at that $A$ is also positive definite?

Comment: @kimchilover Sorry I meant "full *column* rank"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $v \ne 0$, we know that $Xv \ne 0$ by things you already know.

Now look at 
$$
v^t A v = v^t X^t X v =  \langle Xv, Xv \rangle >  0.
$$

Comment: Ah that makes sense. This doesn't make use of $X^TX$ being full rank right?

Comment: Also, my linear algebra is a bit rusty. We know that $Xv \neq 0$ because $X$ is full rank, which means that the nullspace of $X$ is empty, hence $Xv = 0 \iff v = 0$?

Comment: Yep...that's right. (Almost: the nullspace isn't EMPTY, but it does consist solely of the zero vector!)